# jazminschroeder / fedex for Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, fedex

I'm trying to use "jazminschroeder / fedex" gem for shipping, but I need to implement an international shipping for a current application i'm working on for my client. Can someone help me, how international shipping can be done or any documentations(blogs) related to international shipping can be implemented. I searched hours on the internet and could not find anything related to it.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the gem you want is [active_shipping](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping). It seems to be pretty widely used and supported.

Comment: but are there any documentation or resources available regarding international shipping for this gem which I can refer to?

Comment: They have documentation on the github page (which is that link). It looks like you would do something like `destination = Location.new( :country => 'CA', :province => 'ON', :city => 'Ottawa', :postal_code => 'K1P 1J1')`